# Stuck implementing elasticsearch in a flask app

Tags: python, elasticsearch, flask

I'm currently working through the Flask Mega-Tutorial (Part XVI) and have gotten stuck implementing elasticsearch. Specifically, I get this error when running the following from my flask shell command line:

```
from app.search import add_to_index, remove_from_index, query_index
>>> for post in Post.query.all():
...     add_to_index('posts', post) 

AttributeError: module 'flask.app' has no attribute 'elasticsearch'
```

I should mention that I did *not* implement the app restructuring from the previous lesson to use blueprints. Here's what my files look like:

**__init__.py:**

```
#
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
app.elasticsearch = Elasticsearch([app.config['ELASTICSEARCH_URL']]) \
    if app.config['ELASTICSEARCH_URL'] else None
```

**config.py:**

```
class Config(object):
#
     ELASTICSEARCH_URL = 'http://localhost:9200'
```

**search.py:**

```
from flask import app

def add_to_index(index, model):
    if not app.elasticsearch:
        return
    payload = {}
    for field in model.__searchable__:
        payload[field] = getattr(model, field)
    app.elasticsearch.index(index=index, id=model.id, body=payload)

def remove_from_index(index, model):
    if not app.elasticsearch:
        return
    app.elasticsearch.delete(index=index, id=model.id)

def query_index(index, query, page, per_page):
    if not app.elasticsearch:
        return [], 0
    search = app.elasticsearch.search(
        index=index,
        body={'query': {'multi_match': {'query': query, 'fields': ['*']}},
              'from': (page - 1) * per_page, 'size': per_page})
    ids = [int(hit['_id']) for hit in search['hits']['hits']]
    return ids, search['hits']['total']['value']
```

I think I'm not importing elasticsearch correctly into search.py but I'm not sure how to represent it given that I didn't do the restructuring in the last lesson. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to write it in the **search.py** file should be `from flask import current_app`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you got this working, but the way I implemented it was by still using `app.elasticsearch` but instead within `search.py` do:

```
from app import app
```